# Determine the convergence of the sequence $(a_n)$ and find the limit if it exists

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose the sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies

$$        
    0 < \,\,a_n \,<1,\quad a_{n+1}\,(1-a_n)>\frac{1}{4} \qquad(n=1,2,...).
$$
Determine the convergence of the sequence $(a_n)$ and find the limit if it exists.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, observe that $(a_n-\frac{1}{2})^2\ge 0$.  Hence, $a_n^2-a_n+\frac{1}{4}\ge 0$, which rearranges (keeping in mind that $0< a_n< 1$) to $$\frac{1}{4(1-a_n)}\ge a_n$$
Hence, $a_{n+1}>a_n$, so this is a strictly increasing sequence.  However, it is bounded above by $1$, so it must converge to a limit.  Now, what can that limit $L$ be?